# Minimax algorithm bug

Tags: java, algorithm, tic-tac-toe, minimax

I've been trying to learn the minimax algorithm and I've stumbled upon a bug which I cannot figure out how to solve.
Code:

```
    private List<Integer> generatemoves(int[] evalFields) {
    List<Integer> nextMoves = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < evalFields.length; i++) {
        if (evalFields[i] == 0) {
            nextMoves.add(i);
        }
    }
    return nextMoves;
}

private int evaluateLine(int p1, int p2, int p3, int[] evalFields) {
    int score = 0;
    if (evalFields[p1] == 1) {
        score = 1;
    } else if (evalFields[p1] == 10) {
        score = -1;
    }

    if (evalFields[p2] == 1) {
        if (score == 1) {
            score = 10;
        } else if (score == -1) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            score = 1;
        }
    } else if (evalFields[p2] == 10) {
        if (score == -1) {
            score = -10;
        } else if (score == 1) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            score = -1;
        }
    }

    if (evalFields[p3] == 1) {
        if (score > 0) {
            score *= 10;
        } else if (score < 0) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            score = 1;
        }
    } else if (evalFields[p3] == 10) {
        if (score < 0) {
            score *= 10;
        } else if (score > 1) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            score = -1;
        }
    }
    return score;
}

private int evaluateBoard(int [] evalFields) {
    int score = 0;
    score += evaluateLine(0, 1, 2, evalFields);
    score += evaluateLine(3, 4, 5, evalFields);
    score += evaluateLine(6, 7, 8, evalFields);
    score += evaluateLine(0, 3, 6, evalFields);
    score += evaluateLine(1, 4, 7, evalFields);
    score += evaluateLine(2, 5, 8, evalFields);
    score += evaluateLine(0, 4, 8, evalFields);
    score += evaluateLine(2, 4, 6, evalFields);

    return score;
}

private int bestMove(int currentTurn, int[] board) {
    int move;
    int bestScore;
    if (currentTurn == 1) {
        bestScore = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    } else {
        bestScore = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    }
    List<Integer> nextMoves = generatemoves(board);
    List<Integer> bestScores = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < nextMoves.size(); i++) {
        int[] newBoards = new int[9];
        for (int j = 0; j < board.length; j++) {
            newBoards[j] = board[j];
        }
        newBoards[nextMoves.get(i)] = turn;
        bestScores.add(evaluateBoard(newBoards));
    }


    for (int scores : bestScores) {
        if (currentTurn == 1) {
            if (scores > bestScore) bestScore = scores;
        } else {
            if (scores < bestScore) bestScore = scores;
        }
    }
    move = nextMoves.get(bestScores.indexOf(bestScore));

    return move;
}
```

This is the most relevant part of the code. What it does or what I think it does is that it generates every possible move from the board which is called fields. Then it calculates a score for each move. It then proceeds to make the move which results in the highest or lowest score, x(1) is trying to get the  highest and O(10) the lowest. The bug that occurs is that when the player starts and takes the field in the middle, then the ai acts normally but after the players second turn the ai starts to act strange:

```
[ ][ ][ ]    [O][ ][ ]    [O][ ][O]
[ ][x][ ] => [ ][x][ ] => [x][x][ ]
[ ][ ][ ]    [ ][ ][ ]    [ ][ ][ ]
```

If the player chooses this:

```
[O][ ][ ]    [O][ ][ ]
[ ][x][x] => [O][x][x]
[ ][ ][ ]    [ ][ ][ ]
```

Then the ai acts nomally.
I don't know what is wrong or even if I've understood the minimax algorithm correctly.

****edit****
Added this code still have the same problem

```
    private int[] evaluateMove(int [] board, int currentTurn) {
    int bestScore;
    int currentScore;
    int bestMove = -1;
    if (currentTurn == 1) {
        bestScore = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    } else {
        bestScore = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    }

    List<Integer> nextMoves = generatemoves(board);
    if (nextMoves.isEmpty()) {
        bestScore = evaluateTheBoard(board);
    } else {
        for (int move : nextMoves) {
            int[] nextBoard = new int[9];
            for (int i = 0; i < nextBoard.length; i ++) {
                nextBoard[i] = board[i];
            }
            nextBoard[move] = currentTurn;
            currentScore = evaluateMove(nextBoard, nextTurn())[0];
            if (currentTurn == 1) {
                if (currentScore > bestScore) {
                    bestScore = currentScore;
                    bestMove = move;
                }
            } else {
                if (currentScore < bestScore) {
                    bestScore = currentScore;
                    bestMove = move;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return new int[] {bestScore, bestMove};
}
```

Comment: minimax is a scoring convention, not an algorithm. Under minimax, positions which favor one player are negative, and positions which favor the other player are positive. What you actually *do* with that score is the job of the algorithm. The algorithm here is just brute forcing future positions, but examples of named algorithms include Alpha-Beta pruning, MTD(f), Negascout, etc, none of which are necessary for tic-tac-toe because these are just perf optimizations over classic brute force. Also, IMO, negamax scoring is better than minimax scoring and usually results in cleaner code.

Comment: Also, since tic-tac-toe normally results in a draw, especially when you move second, the computer will often see its only choices are to draw, which might explain what you are seeing. When the best option is draw, it will just play whatever and keep the opponent from actually winning. When you say "playing strangely", is it actually letting the player win? Because that would indicate a bug.

Comment: did not go through whole story but is it possible there is a tie of two moves? i.e. having same score? if yes what would you do?

Comment: @shole in the example the player is x, it is possible to have a tie game with those moves. The problem is that the AI is letting the player win.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding how to look ahead in a game like this. Do not 'total' the values returned by `evaluateLine`.

Here is pseudocode for the minimax score of a tic-tac-toe board (what `evaluateBoard` should return). Note that `evaluateBoard` will need to have a notion of `currentTurn`.

```
function evaluateBoard(board, currentTurn)

// check if the game has already ended:
if WhiteHasWon then return -10
if BlackHasWon then return +10

// WhiteHasWon returns true if there exists one or more winning 3-in-a-row line for white. 
// (You will have to scan for all 8 possible 3-in-a-row lines of white pieces)
// BlackHasWon returns true if there exists one or more winning 3-in-a-row line for black

if no legal moves, return 0 // draw

// The game isn't over yet, so look ahead:
bestMove = notset
resultScore = notset
for each legal move i for currentTurn,
   nextBoard = board
   Apply move i to nextBoard
   score = evaluateBoard(nextBoard, NOT currentTurn).score
   if score is <better for currentTurn> than resultScore, then   
      resultScore = score
      bestMove = move i
return (resultScore, bestMove)
```

One very key difference between this and your version and my version is that my version is **recursive**. Yours only goes one level deep. Mine calls `evaluateBoard` from inside `evaluateBoard`, which would be an infinite loop if we aren't careful (once the board fills up, it can't go any deeper, so it's not actually infinite)

Another difference is that yours totals stuff when it shouldn't. The resulting score from tic-tac-toe is -10,0, or 10 only once you've looked to the end of the game. You should be picking the best possible move available to that player at that time, and ignoring all other possibilities completely because you only care about the "best" line of play. The game score is equal to the result of optimal play.

Expanding `<better for currentTurn>` is messy in minimax, which is why negamax is cleaner. White prefers low scores and black prefers high scores, so you need some if statements to make it choose the appropriate preferred score. You have this part already (at the end of your best move code), but it needs to be evaluated inside the recursion instead of just at the end.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I have some questions. The top part of your pseudocode do just check if either black or white won or if it's a tie? or do i still need the evaluateLine function? I also can't figure out how to extract the right move from the evaluateBoard function, if you could clarify that that would be great.

Comment: Maybe I misread it, but I thought evaluateLine was looking for 3-in-a-row lines which indicate victory. What you need to check for game end is to look for any 3-in-a-row lines (which win the game). If one (or more) exists for white, then the score is -10, and the same for black.

Comment: I updated the answer to show how you can extract the best move from evaluateBoard, if you want to have the answer come out of that function. You could also, go further and build up a the entire expected move sequence too, so you can see the line of play that the computer liked.

Comment: I've played around with your solution a bit. The AI did not get any smarter. I've kept most of the code the same I've only added your function.

Comment: Just to clarify the AI is letting the player win even more often with the recursive function, Im almost sure that's not what should happen.

Comment: Your current code doesn't appear to detect a winning condition, and keeps going deeper until nextMoves.isEmpty() returns true. Doesn't that mean it ignores 3 in a row and keeps searching until the whole board is full, instead of stopping when the game is won? And even then it still doesn't reward victory, which is the root of the problem. You appear to have forgotten the "if there exists one or more winning 3-in-a-row line for white, return -10" step in the pseudocode.

Comment: I believe the previous comment is the main issue, but also, you should write tests for your code and add `assert`s to make sure the parts work. For example, I would `assert` that `evaluateMove` never returns `Integer.MIN_VALUE` nor `Integer.MAX_VALUE` because this always indicates a bug. Also, I don't trust the way you did `nextTurn()`... this should be a function of `currentTurn`, e.g. `nextTurn(currentTurn)` returns the opposite turn.

Comment: It works for now I haven't experienced strange play from the AI yet. I've also read on the internet that i needed to apply depth to the scoring to fix these strange plays. I think i did that wrong which messed with the AI when i tested it with a `hasWon()` and a better `nextTurn()` function. It works as I want it to work so I don't need depth. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Yes, the code I gave is intolerant to cutting the depth off. It's best to look ahead to the end, if the game is simple enough for this to be feasible. In complex games like chess, we have to generate an "estimate" of who's winning after 10 moves ahead, etc. To make a tic-tac-toe game tolerant of only looking say 2 moves ahead, we'd need code that "estimates" who is winning as a minimax score (or it would just pick randomly). But, there is no good way to generate such an estimate in tic-tac-toe that is better than simply looking further ahead, so its best to look ahead until someone has won.

Comment: Ahh okay, it does make sense though.